# List of PayPal transactions

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, paypal

Here's the setup:

I have a site setup for a client. The customer:

1. Visits the site
2. Enters in basic information for our records
3. Proceeds to PayPal via a "Buy Now" button
4. Makes the payment through PayPal
5. Returns to the site

What I am wanting to know is how do I get a list of all the transactions? I have the PayPal login as well as the API username, password, and signature, but for the life of me I cannot find a single place on the internet that gives an example of how to pull a list of transactions from PayPal either via PHP or jQuery/Javascript/Ajax.

Does anyone have any ideas? examples?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to develop a solution to this question. See my answer below with code and comments.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, so I finally was able to develop something that works. The code is posted below with a link to the TransactionSearch API options from PayPal

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/

```
<?php 
$info = 'USER=[API_USERNAME]'
        .'&PWD=[API_PASSWORD]'
        .'&SIGNATURE=[API_SIGNATURE]'
        .'&METHOD=TransactionSearch'
        .'&TRANSACTIONCLASS=RECEIVED'
        .'&STARTDATE=2013-01-08T05:38:48Z'
        .'&ENDDATE=2013-07-14T05:38:48Z'
        .'&VERSION=94';

$curl = curl_init('https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $info);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

# Bust the string up into an array by the ampersand (&)
# You could also use parse_str(), but it would most likely limit out
$result = explode("&", $result);

# Loop through the new array and further bust up each element by the equal sign (=)
# and then create a new array with the left side of the equal sign as the key and the right side of the equal sign as the value
foreach($result as $value){
    $value = explode("=", $value);
    $temp[$value[0]] = $value[1];
}

# At the time of writing this code, there were 11 different types of responses that were returned for each record
# There may only be 10 records returned, but there will be 110 keys in our array which contain all the different pieces of information for each record
# Now create a 2 dimensional array with all the information for each record together
for($i=0; $i<count($temp)/11; $i++){
    $returned_array[$i] = array(
        "timestamp"         =>    urldecode($temp["L_TIMESTAMP".$i]),
        "timezone"          =>    urldecode($temp["L_TIMEZONE".$i]),
        "type"              =>    urldecode($temp["L_TYPE".$i]),
        "email"             =>    urldecode($temp["L_EMAIL".$i]),
        "name"              =>    urldecode($temp["L_NAME".$i]),
        "transaction_id"    =>    urldecode($temp["L_TRANSACTIONID".$i]),
        "status"            =>    urldecode($temp["L_STATUS".$i]),
        "amt"               =>    urldecode($temp["L_AMT".$i]),
        "currency_code"     =>    urldecode($temp["L_CURRENCYCODE".$i]),
        "fee_amount"        =>    urldecode($temp["L_FEEAMT".$i]),
        "net_amount"        =>    urldecode($temp["L_NETAMT".$i]));
}
?>
```

Also, I came up with this nifty little, simple script to get more details about a particular transaction:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/

```
<?php 
$info =  'USER=[API_USERNAME]'
        .'&PWD=[API_PASSWORD]'
        .'&SIGNATURE=[API_SIGNATURE]'
        .'&VERSION=94'
        .'&METHOD=GetTransactionDetails'
        .'&TRANSACTIONID=[TRANSACTION_ID]'
        .'&STARTDATE=2013-07-08T05:38:48Z'
        .'&ENDDATE=2013-07-12T05:38:48Z';

$curl = curl_init('https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $info);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

parse_str($result, $result);

foreach($result as $key => $value){
    echo $key.' => '.$value."<BR>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the first coding to display transaction but I got `SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for`
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\all_transactions.php on line 40` error

Comment: This appears to be a PHP error as if you have a character out of place or something. Re-check your code because without seeing your code I wouldn't even know where to begin.

Comment: I coded the first coding solution you have given in this answer starting with `<?php 
$info =  'USER=[API_USERNAME]'
        .'&PWD=[API_PASSWORD]'
        .'&SIGNATURE=[API_SIGNATURE]'
        .'&VERSION=94'
        .'&METHOD=GetTransactionDetails'
        .'&TRANSACTIONID=[TRANSACTION_ID]'` I changed my username, pwd and signature but its not working.

Comment: There are two errors in the first code snippet above. The returned_array array that pulls together the data returned from paypal should be constructed with "key" => "value" and not "key" = "value". Also the values for this array should be taken from $temp and not $result. Your script then creates the transaction arrays with the correct transaction data from paypal.

Comment: You truly are the Duke! I've posted the corrected code here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561873/how-to-access-3rd-party-transaction-information-in-paypal/24562130#24562130

Answer (score 0):

They have a TransactionSearch API:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/

I use mine pull by invoice number to retrieve transaction ids for refunding.

Comment: I appreciate the help and the code, but without the PHP class behind it that you are using, all that you posted was just a bunch of variables. Do you have the code, or a link to the code, of the class that you're using?

Comment: You can use the Angell EYE class.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script
    data-env="sandbox"
    data-tax="0.00"
    data-shipping="0.00"
    data-currency="USD"
    data-amount="0.00"
    data-quantity="0"
    data-name="No Item Selected"
    data-button="buynow" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=ben4xfer@gmail.com" async="async"></script>
```

This is a html element that hooks up to the paypal API to make a transaction when the button is clicked. Do not change the `data-button`, `src`, or `async` properties. Completly remove the `data-env` node after you are finished testing (the `data-env` node prevents an actual charge from being made while you are testing). Change all of the other properties according to their names (e.g you would change `data-name` to the name of the product you are selling). Insert the element as you would any other html element (e.g. `<p>`).