# List all Paypal transaction ids

Tags: php, paypal, transactions

I am doing a website, on which I have integrated paypal payments in sandbox mode. I want to list all the transactions that I made to my **sandbox** merchant account via a php file. I am a beginner to paypal API, but I have username, password and signature for my sand-boxed merchant account. I tried this code which I found in [List of PayPal transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618836/list-of-paypal-transactions)

```
<?php 
$info = 'USER=[API_USERNAME]'
        .'&PWD=[API_PASSWORD]'
        .'&SIGNATURE=[API_SIGNATURE]'
        .'&METHOD=TransactionSearch'
        .'&TRANSACTIONCLASS=RECEIVED'
        .'&STARTDATE=2013-01-08T05:38:48Z'
        .'&ENDDATE=2013-07-14T05:38:48Z'
        .'&VERSION=94';

$curl = curl_init('https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $info);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

# Bust the string up into an array by the ampersand (&)
# You could also use parse_str(), but it would most likely limit out
$result = explode("&", $result);

# Loop through the new array and further bust up each element by the equal sign (=)
# and then create a new array with the left side of the equal sign as the key and the right side of the equal sign as the value
foreach($result as $value){
    $value = explode("=", $value);
    $temp[$value[0]] = $value[1];
}

# At the time of writing this code, there were 11 different types of responses that were returned for each record
# There may only be 10 records returned, but there will be 110 keys in our array which contain all the different pieces of information for each record
# Now create a 2 dimensional array with all the information for each record together
for($i=0; $i<count($temp)/11; $i++){
    $returned_array[$i] = array(
        "timestamp"         =    urldecode($result["L_TIMESTAMP".$i]),
        "timezone"          =    urldecode($result["L_TIMEZONE".$i]),
        "type"              =    urldecode($result["L_TYPE".$i]),
        "email"             =    urldecode($result["L_EMAIL".$i]),
        "name"              =    urldecode($result["L_NAME".$i]),
        "transaction_id"    =    urldecode($result["L_TRANSACTIONID".$i]),
        "status"            =    urldecode($result["L_STATUS".$i]),
        "amt"               =    urldecode($result["L_AMT".$i]),
        "currency_code"     =    urldecode($result["L_CURRENCYCODE".$i]),
        "fee_amount"        =    urldecode($result["L_FEEAMT".$i]),
        "net_amount"        =    urldecode($result["L_NETAMT".$i]));
}
?>
```

but this is saying `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\all_transactions.php on line 40`
 Thought the above code gives all details, I need only the transaction id.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  I pasted your code into my editor, and I'm only showing 33 total lines with no syntax errors being reported.  Since you're working with PHP I'd recommend checking out my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/).  It'll make API calls to PayPal very simple for you.

Comment: @AndrewAngell No man, Its 52 lines of code. I will try yours. :)

Comment: @AndrewAngell I tried with your class. But its returning error 'Security header is not valid' but I am damn sure about my credentials.

Comment: Oh yeah, ha, I didn't scroll down so I wasn't getting the bottom of your script.  As @machavity explained you're using the wrong syntax for your array.

Comment: As for the security header you're getting with my library, if you're sure the credentials are correct then you must not have $sandbox set the way you think, so you're sending sandbox credentials to the live server or vice-versa.  One way or another, security header ALWAYS means your credentials aren't correct.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong syntax for `array`. It should be `$key => $value`

```
$returned_array[$i] = array(
    "timestamp"         =>    urldecode($result["L_TIMESTAMP".$i]),
    "timezone"          =>    urldecode($result["L_TIMEZONE".$i]),
    "type"              =>    urldecode($result["L_TYPE".$i]),
    "email"             =>    urldecode($result["L_EMAIL".$i]),
    "name"              =>    urldecode($result["L_NAME".$i]),
    "transaction_id"    =>    urldecode($result["L_TRANSACTIONID".$i]),
    "status"            =>    urldecode($result["L_STATUS".$i]),
    "amt"               =>    urldecode($result["L_AMT".$i]),
    "currency_code"     =>    urldecode($result["L_CURRENCYCODE".$i]),
    "fee_amount"        =>    urldecode($result["L_FEEAMT".$i]),
    "net_amount"        =>    urldecode($result["L_NETAMT".$i])
);
```