# How to access 3rd party transaction information in Paypal

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to figure out how to access transaction information from a third party user (to include in a dashboard) from Paypal.

Ideally I need to be able to pull in transaction data, without having to manually authorize the app everytime, as a lot of it needs to happen in the background. So far using a test account, I can see how I could obtain the API username, password and signature which I guess I would need to use.

Which API would I use for this (Classic / Rest) and which method of authentication would be safest?

Answer (score 5):

After struggling with this for sometime I found a simple, but crude implementation here - [List of PayPal transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618836/list-of-paypal-transactions).

The original code didn't work - here's a corrected version

```
<?php 
 $info = 'USER=[API_USERNAME]'
    .'&PWD=[API_PASSWORD]'
    .'&SIGNATURE=[API_SIGNATURE]'
    .'&METHOD=TransactionSearch'
    .'&TRANSACTIONCLASS=RECEIVED'
    .'&STARTDATE=2013-01-08T05:38:48Z'
    .'&ENDDATE=2013-07-14T05:38:48Z'
    .'&VERSION=94';

$curl = curl_init('https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $info);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

# Bust the string up into an array by the ampersand (&)
 # You could also use parse_str(), but it would most likely limit out
 $result = explode("&", $result);

# Loop through the new array and further bust up each element by the equal sign (=)
# and then create a new array with the left side of the equal sign as the key and the       right side of the equal sign as the value
   foreach($result as $value){
$value = explode("=", $value);
$temp[$value[0]] = $value[1];
}


for($i=0; $i<(count($temp)/11)-1; $i++){
    $returned_array[$i] = array(
    "timestamp"         =>    urldecode($temp["L_TIMESTAMP".$i]),
    "timezone"          =>    urldecode($temp["L_TIMEZONE".$i]),
    "type"              =>    urldecode($temp["L_TYPE".$i]),
    "email"             =>    urldecode($temp["L_EMAIL".$i]),
    "name"              =>    urldecode($temp["L_NAME".$i]),
    "transaction_id"    =>   urldecode($temp["L_TRANSACTIONID".$i]),
    "status"            =>    urldecode($temp["L_STATUS".$i]),
    "amt"               =>    urldecode($temp["L_AMT".$i]),
    "currency_code"     =>    urldecode($temp["L_CURRENCYCODE".$i]),
    "fee_amount"        =>    urldecode($temp["L_FEEAMT".$i]),
    "net_amount"        =>    urldecode($temp["L_NETAMT".$i]));
}

var_dump($returned_array);
```

This is obviously not production code, but it's good enough to work backwards from.