# Getting list of transactions on paypal

Tags: php, api, paypal

I can't seem to get a list of all paypal transactions. I'm trying to use paypal APIs but I can't seem to understand. I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561873/how-to-access-3rd-party-transaction-information-in-paypal/24562130#24562130) but couldn't get it to work. When pasting it into a php file, inserting the username, password and signature, i get an error.

> Warning: curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set in /home/u925636669/public_html/system.php on line 13
>   NULL

I'm not that good in PHP so help would be appreciated.
If you could, I would also like to use that code to return an array of all the transactions with info about how much was paid, by whom and when.

Also, is there a way to test it without paying anything?

Comment: use paypal sandbox to test

Comment: I would recommend using [this library](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/).  It includes TransactionSearch and GetTransactionDetails already setup and ready to go for you.  You could get this done in minutes.

Comment: How do i install it? Could you send me a tutorial? Also, i'm on a host so im not sure i can install such things

Comment: @AndrewAngell Forgot to notify you. look at my previous comment

Comment: Install details are available at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  It can be installed via Composer or manually.

Comment: @AndrewAngell How to install using composer? (i'm a 100% php noob)

Comment: May be easier for you to just install manually then.  The details are available at the link I provided in the previous comment.

Comment: @AndrewAngell I checked out their tutorial and i can't seem to find the "includes" folder :( Maybe you can send me a better download? Thanks m9

Comment: Eh, I guess that could be a little confusing.  The config file is included in the /samples.  You can place that anywhere you want and adjust the samples/templates accordingly.  Or you can just create your own /includes folder at the site root and place the config file in there.  Then you'll just need to make sure you have the config file setup correctly and you'll be ready to rock.

Comment: If you want more direct help with that you can [submit a ticket here](http://www.angelleye.com/support).