# Get all transactions using PayPal API

Tags: php, api, paypal, payment-gateway, express-checkout

I am new in PayPal API and I am using ExpressCheckout for all payment transactions. What I want is, To get all the payments received transactions using `start_time` and `end_time` so that I will know what are the status of this transactions.

The purpose of this is that my system is aware about the status of all payments from time to time.

I am also confused if this is possible in sandbox. If it is possible please help me.

I am working this for a week using php language. I follow the link in PayPal but I still don't get the it. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#paging--filtering

Please if you have a nice tip please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Are you working with PHP? If yes then please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618836/list-of-paypal-transactions

Answer (score 3):

@Developer Status' answer is a good sample, but I would recommend using this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/), specifically the [TransactionSearch](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-sdk/blob/dev/templates/TransactionSearch.php) template which makes the call very simple for you.  It handles parsing all of the results for you, too.  [Here you can see a sample of the full result including parsed search results](http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/samples/TransactionSearch.php) (you may need to scroll down a little to see the parsed SEARCHRESULTS.)

As you loop through those results you'll most likely need to also hit [GetTransactionDetails](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-sdk/blob/dev/templates/GetTransactionDetails.php) for each one to obtain all of the info you need.  Again, that template in the SDK will make that very simple for you.

So if you download that SDK, adjust the config file with your own API credentials, and then load up that sample/template you can have this working within minutes.

I would also recommend that you take a look at [PayPal IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).  This will allow you to get real-time updates when transactions hit your account so you can automate everything in real-time as opposed to hitting the TransactionSearch API at specific intervals.

Answer (score 1):

```
 # You can put start date and end date here in request for `STARTDATE` AND `ENDDATE` #

 <?php 
 $info = 'USER=[API_USERNAME]'
        .'&PWD=[API_PASSWORD]'
        .'&SIGNATURE=[API_SIGNATURE]'
        .'&METHOD=TransactionSearch'
        .'&TRANSACTIONCLASS=RECEIVED'
        .'&STARTDATE=2013-01-08T05:38:48Z'
        .'&ENDDATE=2013-07-14T05:38:48Z'
        .'&VERSION=94';

$curl = curl_init('https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $info);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

# Bust the string up into an array by the ampersand (&)
# You could also use parse_str(), but it would most likely limit out
$result = explode("&", $result);

# Loop through the new array and further bust up each element by the equal sign (=)
# and then create a new array with the left side of the equal sign as the key and the right side of the equal sign as the value
foreach($result as $value){
    $value = explode("=", $value);
    $temp[$value[0]] = $value[1];
}

# At the time of writing this code, there were 11 different types of responses that were returned for each record
# There may only be 10 records returned, but there will be 110 keys in our array which contain all the different pieces of information for each record
# Now create a 2 dimensional array with all the information for each record together
for($i=0; $i<count($temp)/11; $i++){
    $returned_array[$i] = array(
        "timestamp"         =    urldecode($result["L_TIMESTAMP".$i]),
        "timezone"          =    urldecode($result["L_TIMEZONE".$i]),
        "type"              =    urldecode($result["L_TYPE".$i]),
        "email"             =    urldecode($result["L_EMAIL".$i]),
        "name"              =    urldecode($result["L_NAME".$i]),
        "transaction_id"    =    urldecode($result["L_TRANSACTIONID".$i]),
        "status"            =    urldecode($result["L_STATUS".$i]),
        "amt"               =    urldecode($result["L_AMT".$i]),
        "currency_code"     =    urldecode($result["L_CURRENCYCODE".$i]),
        "fee_amount"        =    urldecode($result["L_FEEAMT".$i]),
        "net_amount"        =    urldecode($result["L_NETAMT".$i]));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<?
     $info = 'USER=[API_USERNAME]'
            .'&PWD=[API_PASSWORD]'
            .'&SIGNATURE=[API_SIGNATURE]'
            .'&METHOD=TransactionSearch'
            .'&TRANSACTIONCLASS=RECEIVED'
            .'&STARTDATE=2013-01-08T05:38:48Z'
            .'&ENDDATE=2013-07-14T05:38:48Z'
            .'&VERSION=94';

    $curl = curl_init('https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $info);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    $result = explode("&", $result);

    foreach($result as $value){
        $value = explode("=", $value);
        $temp[$value[0]] = $value[1];
    }


    foreach($temp as $k=>$v){
        $i++;
        preg_match('#^(.*?)([0-9]+)$#is',$k,$str);
        $num=$str[2];
        $key=preg_replace('#^[A-z]_#','',$str[1]);
        if($key!=''){

        $new[$num][$key]=urldecode($v); 
        }

    }
    print_R($new);

?>
```