# PayPal Notification on Payment Sent

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

All documentation I can find for PayPal development is focused on capturing payments from a customer. Even IPN and Webhook events are all about taking action when payments are received.

I operate a small press and my primary use of PayPal is to send payments to authors. I need to take certain actions when payment is sent from my PayPal account to many different recipients.

Using any PayPal API, how do I programmatically retrieve a list of recent payments I have sent? Alternatively, how can I receive a webhook notification when I **send** a payment through PayPal instead of when I receive one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618836/list-of-paypal-transactions should give you a good place to start (with `TRANSACTIONCLASS=SENT`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TransactionSearch API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) would allow you to pull transactions based on different types.  It uses the Classic API, though, not REST.

[IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) would send notifications when any transaction hits in your account, including payments you send from it via send_money, masspay, or the Pay API.

Comment: You can find your IPN log under https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history and for as far as I can tell it only records/sends notifications for the incoming payments.